# Java script dynamically add video element in grid HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display videos in grid as shown in the example here http://jsfiddle.net/5qdojj83/

I have modified the code to add the video from JavaScript dynamically, but now it seems the boarder of the grid with different width.

I have used fixed width in  JS for video because the source video can be with different resolution and size.

What wrong with below code?

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Image Grids Using CSS</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

.videoGrid {
    border-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    background-color:orange;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.videoBg {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoBg video{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="videoGrid">
    <tr id="video_table">
    </tr>     
</table>

 <script>
loadImages();
 function loadImages(){

               var urls = ["http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
        ];
                        
                for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          var obj = urls[i];

                   var source = document.createElement('video');
                   source.width=400;
          source.height=300;  
          source.src = obj;
                   source.controls = true;
          source.type = "mp4";
                   

     var td  = document.createElement("td");
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.className = "videoBg";
       div.appendChild(source);
                    td.appendChild(div);

                    document.getElementById("video_table").appendChild(td);
         }

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Image Grids Using CSS</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

.videoGrid {
    border-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    background-color:orange;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.videoBg {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoBg video{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

video{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="videoGrid">
    <tr id="video_table">
    </tr>     
</table>

 <script>
loadImages();
 function loadImages(){

               var urls = ["http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
       "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
        ];
                        
                for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          var obj = urls[i];

                   var source = document.createElement('video');
                   
          source.src = obj;
                   source.controls = true;
          source.type = "mp4";
                   

     var td  = document.createElement("td");
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.className = "videoBg";
       div.appendChild(source);
                    td.appendChild(div);

                    document.getElementById("video_table").appendChild(td);
         }

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```